# How fast is Stanford's CoreNLP sentiment analysis tool?

Tags: stanford-nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

1. I'm trying to find out whether it's feasible for me to use the the CoreNLP sentiment analysis tool (http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html) on a dataset equivalent in size to about 1 million IMDB reviews.

I could not find any absolute metrics anywhere online about average times. I would appreciate if someone could point me to any place about these statistics regarding the speed.

2. Also, this is what I'm trying - to see if it's possible to estimate a movie rating by using the text alone i.e. by summing up scores for each sentence in a review. Does anything in my idea or in the code snippet below look stupid (should be done better)? I get the feeling that I might be using this tool for something that it's not suited for or I'm doing it the wrong way.

   ```
   public static double getTextSentimentScore(String text){
   Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(text);
   double sum = 0;
   List<CoreMap> sentences = (List<CoreMap>) annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
   int i = 0;
   for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
       String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);
       int sentimentScore = 0;
       if (sentiment.equals("Very positive"))
           sentimentScore = 5;
       if (sentiment.equals("Positive"))
           sentimentScore = 4;
       if (sentiment.equals("Neutral"))
           sentimentScore = 3;
       if (sentiment.equals("Negative"))
           sentimentScore = 2;
       if (sentiment.equals("Very negative"))
           sentimentScore = 1;
       sum += sentimentScore;
       System.out.println(sentiment + "\t" + sentimentScore);
   }
   return (sum/sentences.size());
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this command:

```
java -Xmx5g -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse,sentiment -filelist list-of-sample-docs.txt
```

the final output will give you timing information

So all you have to do is:

1. take 100 IMDB reviews, put them in files named imdb_review_1, imdb_review_2, etc...
2. put each filename one file per line in list-of-sample-docs.txts
3. run that command and the final output will show total time for each annotator and total time elapsed